# Why I can't replace word with variable using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How can I replace string in file using sed?
Here is my code :

```
inac=`echo "\#$minute\ $hour\ $date\ $month\ $day\ $cron_user\ $comm"`
actv=`echo "$minute\ $hour\ $date\ $month\ $day\ $cron_user\ $comm"`

if [[ $stat == "active" ]]; then
     sed -i "s/^.${inac}/${actv}/" filecron
     active
     echo "input data active to filecron"

fi
```

And I've try with :

```
sed -i 's/"#all all all all all root bash /media/data/looping.sh > /dev/null 2>&1"/"all all all all all root bash /media/data/looping.sh > /dev/null 2>&1"/' filecron
```

The point is, I just want to remove the "#" sign if stat value is active. If there is a better alternative rather than using sed, I would be appriciate.
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Where is `$stat` coming from, and wouldn't you be setting it to `active` if it were `inactive`?

Comment: $stat was come from database. i just want to delete # where record in database was in active status.

Comment: If all you want to do is add/delete the leading `#` then write your pattern to do that. Don't mess around with replacing (and matching) the whole line like that. It just complicates and confuses things.

Comment: ow, i'm sorry if make you confuse. i'm not really familiar with sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it's doing all kinds of unnecessary things. I assume you've got a commented out line in filecron:

```
#all all all all all root bash /media/data/looping.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If you want to remove all the `#`'s in filecron this should be all that is needed:

```
if [[ $stat == "active" ]]; then
     sed -i '' 's/#//g' filecron
     active
     echo "input data active to filecron"
fi
```

warning: `-i ''` does an in-place edit with no backup, so caution should be exercised. If you want to make a backup, then instead of `''` specify a filename.